# Access the values of components in react-admin

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest, react-admin

I want to access values of components. Because I'll use it to access to another data. For example;

```
<ArrayInput source='services'>
    <SimpleFormIterator>
        <ReferenceInput label="Service Type"
            source="serviceType"
            reference="servicetypes"
            validate={required()}>
            <SelectInput optionText={GAMMA_CONSTANTS.SOURCE_ID} />
        </ReferenceInput>
        {(this.state.serviceTypes && this.state.serviceTypes.length > 0) ?
            this.state.serviceTypes.filter(serviceType => {
                    return serviceType.id === (**source="serviceType"**)
                })[0]["datapointtype"].map((feature, index) => {
                return <TextInput source={index} label="deneme" />
            })
            : null}

    </SimpleFormIterator>
</ArrayInput>
```

I want to access it in the filter method. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Are you using admin-on-rest or react-admin ?

Comment: I'm using react-admin

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
import { FormDataConsumer } from 'react-admin';

const PostEdit = (props) => (
    <Edit {...props}>
        <SimpleForm>
            <BooleanInput source="hasEmail" />
            <FormDataConsumer>
                {({ formData, ...rest }) => formData.hasEmail &&
                     <TextInput source="email" {...rest} />
                }
            </FormDataConsumer>
        </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
);
```

Reference: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#hiding-inputs-based-on-other-inputs

You're not limited to hide/show things. In your case, you should be able to avoid using state and directly access `formData.serviceTypes`

Comment: Yeah, your solution works well for single components. But I haven't mentioned the key point in my case, sorry fot that. I did a little change in the code part in the post. There is a ArrayInput and I want to bind one by one this ArrayInput's values. For example in the services array, the 0. "ReferenceInput" value need to bind 0. loop, the 1. "ReferenceInput" value to 1.loop and so on. Is there a solution for that case too?

Comment: I set up a codesandbox and added a "services" ArrayInput in the CommentCreate Page. Basically I want to send the text that I entered in "serviceName "textbox. If I can do that I'll return a choice list related to this serviceName in a function (for SelectArrayInput). I don't know is it clear for you or Could I tell clearly what I want   

[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/92w2rxj54o)

Comment: In the CommentCreate I've added a ArrayInput element and this causes that the page is broken. I don't know why because I use it like that in my local code and there is no error

Comment: I found the problem why the create page isn't opening. There is a bug about RefenceInput I guess. Now the page is ok. Is it cleae what I want in the code?

https://codesandbox.io/s/92w2rxj54o

Comment: Nope sorry, I don't get it